# How to parse "TRUE"(String, key name) in api with JSONObject?

Tags: android, json, parsing

[image: TRUE in api as key name]

I have to parse api about cryptocurrency exchange. It includes cryptocurrency named "TRUE", and makes JSONException. Well... JSONObject cognize "TRUE" as Boolean data.  JSONObject have probably seen "TRUE=" as a comparison of Boolean values. That makes me seriously laugh, and was very funny but obviously is problem I have to solve. How to parse Json having "TRUE" as key name? It's okay if solution is using Gson.

https://api.bithumb.com/public/ticker/ALL_KRW

This is API link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
String s= "
           "TRUE" : { 
                   "opening_price":"394.4"
                    }
          "

 JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject("{" + s +"}");
 Log.d("JSON",jsonObject.getJSONObject("TRUE").getString("opening_price"));
```